# .split in IE 7 not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7, split

I am trying to split an AJAX response with .split() in IE 7 and i am just getting *Object doesn't support this property or method*, I am using the following code:

> info = data.split("&");

Where data = 1&2&3&4

If I run on console '1&2&3&4'.split(); it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

Thanks a lot, I just figured it out, the porblem was *info* wasn't defined as string.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(typeof data);`? Or `data.toString().split("&");`

Comment: your example does not include the & symbol, is it supposed to?

Comment: What do you mean "_info_ wasn't defined as string"? You are setting the `info` variable to whatever the return from the `.split()` is, it doesn't matter what type it held before that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a method of the object. Convert to a string first.